# Using Xcode to make platform independent app

Tags: c++, xcode, cross-platform, executable, sdl

I have a program written in C++ using the [SDL library](http://www.libsdl.org/) in XCode. 
I need to send the program to somebody and I need to be sure that they can run it without having to paste the source into an IDE, import SDL, and so on. I am sending the file by the means of another person, so I do not know the final recipient's name (I can't ask them anything) or operating system. I can make executable scripts that run on Mac just fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You'll have to build the source for the target platform anyway, as C++ is not an interpreted language.

Comment: If I have to make separate executables for linux and windows, that is fine. I have no knowledge of doing either.

Comment: The easier and most straightforward way to get reasonable multiplatform build generator is to use cmake. With a little help, it will adapt your different needs (libs) to your targets. Since there is little chance your recipient has the correct setup (cmake+compiler+libs) or knowledge, if you have access to linux/windows (for example using virtualbox), build the executables yourself then. That is certainly two days work if you do not know anything about cmake, but know the target platforms.

Answer (score 0):

The SDL framework isn't preinstalled in OS X, so your recipient will almost certainly need to do some work to get it installed somehow (e.g. via MacPorts). I don't think you will be able to deliver a no-effort solution where they just double-click an xcodeproj, hit build, and it just works.

Your best bet is to get access to a second Mac, get your program building on that, and document all the steps you needed to do to get it to work. (Install Xcode 4.x, install MacPorts, install SDL, etc.)

Comment: Ouch. That's more than I can ask of someone. I am submitting the files as a supplement to a CV for an interview.

Comment: If they are worth working for, they should be able to read the code and get a feel for your programming aptitude without actually needing to compile it. I have read many resumes and not once have I actually attempted to compile and debug their code.